# ASP .NET Core model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-binding

I'm using Visual Studio 16.4.6 and working on a ASP .NET Web application using SDK 2.2.  My problem is that an embedded object in my model is being set to null after a Submit is issued.  Here's some of the details.

```
class Photo {
    public int GardenId { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public bool isDisplayed { get; set; }
}

class garden {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

The model passed into the View (for editing purposes) is garden.  When the data comes into the View, everything is populated correctly, including the ICollection Photos Object having values.  The view is able to access the Photos object and display the associated files.  However, when the submit button is pressed to process changes, the model passed back into the controller method has a null value for the Photos object.  Essentially, the Photos object is being dropped when the model is passed back to the controller. The other garden object properties are present with the updates.  Even when only the submit button is pressed and no properties are edited, the same thing occurs.  Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add View code.

Comment: Maybe these classes must be `public`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The view is able to access the Photos object and display the associated files. However, when the submit button is pressed to process changes, the model passed back into the controller method has a null value for the Photos object.

To troubleshoot the above issue about the posted data not be bound to properties well, please check if the form data you posted look like below using browser F12 developer tools Network tool.

[image]

And you can refer to the following code snippet to display `Photos` related information in your form.

```
@model garden

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    var Photos = Model.Photos.ToList();
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>garden</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Photos.Count(); i++)
            {
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Photos[i].GardenId" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Photos[i].Filename" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@Photos[i].Filename" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Photos[i].isDisplayed" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@Photos[i].isDisplayed" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: You can know more about "Model Binding in ASP.NET Core" from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections

Comment: Hello Fei - thanks vary much for your response, which helped me to correct the model binding problem.  My original code (in the View file) was accessing the Model directly (e.g. Model.Photos.ElementAt(i).Filename).  Changing this to assign the Photos object to a local variable worked, although I'm still not clear why accessing the Model directly didn't work.  I'll follow-up on the link you sent.